# geom_contour for a specific value

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour

In this example, is it possible to just plot one contour line? For example, contour just where is 0.025?

```
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(eruptions, waiting)) + 
geom_contour(aes(z = density, colour = ..level..))
```

Comment: How about `geom_contour(..., breaks = 0.025)`?

Comment: (FYI, `..level..` is deprecated, `colour=after_stat(level)` is now recommended/preferred.)

Comment: it doesn't work, I get ```Warning message:
In geom_contour(aes(z = density, colour = after_stat(level), breaks = 0.025)) :
  Ignoring unknown aesthetics: breaks```

Comment: Of course do you have to put `breaks` outside of `aes()`.